# joining tables in salesforce explorer

Tags: salesforce, soql

trying to join lead table with opportunity table in force.com explorer.  New to soql.  Here is what I have tried with error messages as results... can anyone help please?

SELECT CreatedDate, LeadSource, RecordTypeId, Name__c, StageName, HubSpot_Original_Source_Data_1__c, Name, HubSpot_Original_Source_Data_2__c, HubSpot_Original_Source_Type__c, (SELECT Company, IsConverted, CreatedDate, HubSpot_Inc__HubSpot_Intelligence__c, HubSpot_Original_Source_Data_1__c, HubSpot_Original_Source_Data_2__c, HubSpot_Original_Source_Type__c, LeadSource, RecordTypeId FROM Lead) FROM Opportunity where Name in (select Company from Lead)

Answer (score 0):

Where clause of your query will not work. You can use another query in where clause only for checking matching Id.

```
SELECT CreatedDate, LeadSource, RecordTypeId, Name__c, StageName, HubSpot_Original_Source_Data_1__c, Name, HubSpot_Original_Source_Data_2__c, HubSpot_Original_Source_Type__c, (SELECT Company, IsConverted, CreatedDate, HubSpot_Inc__HubSpot_Intelligence__c, HubSpot_Original_Source_Data_1__c, HubSpot_Original_Source_Data_2__c, HubSpot_Original_Source_Type__c, LeadSource, RecordTypeId FROM Lead) FROM Opportunity where name = 'test'
```

Comment: how will the query know what field to join on?

Comment: Whenever you are using another query in WHERE clause, only ID will be used for matching. If any other field need to be used for matching, you cannot use query. Instead you have to query, get corresponding values into a set/list then use like "where Name =: nameSet"